# How to switch between ModelSim and VSIM in transcript window?

Tags: modelsim

When we first open ModelSim, the transcript window shows `ModelSim>`.

However, after entering something like `vsim -view mywaveform.wlf`, it changes to `VSIM 2>`, and trying `quit -sim` doesn't switch back to `ModelSim>` but instead closes ModelSim directly.

How is it possible to switch between `ModelSim>` and `VSIM n>` in the transcript window?

Answer (score 0):

- To quit `VSIM >` after simulation, use `quit -sim`.
- To quit `VSIM >` after `vsim -view mywaveform.wlf`, use `dataset close mywaveform`. Alternatively, go to File->Datasets and close the dataset manually.